# Encountering " WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize" error when running Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I installed Spark and when trying to run it, I am getting the error:

> `WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped`

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same problem occured with me because python path was not added to system environment. I added this in environment and now it works perfectly.

Adding `PYTHONPATH` environment variable with value as:

```sh
%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%
```

helped resolve this issue. Just check what py4j version you have in your `spark/python/lib folder`.

Comment: I know it might be late, but maybe this video helps you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQErwxRTiW0

I had exactly the same issue, changed pathes, did everything but still got the same message. Then I decided to go his approach and it works

Comment: Where should I run this command?

Answer (score 15):

I received this same message, running Spark 3.0.1 on Windows 10, using Scala 2.12.10.  It's not actually an Error, in the sense that it ends your program execution.  Its a warning related to /proc file systems on Linux machines.

If you are also on a Windows machine, the answer maybe, to quote Wing Yew Poon @ Apache: "The warning happened because the command "getconf PAGESIZE" was run and it is not a valid command on Windows so an exception was caught." (From the Spark jira issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33001?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17232192#comment-17232192)).

If your program failed right after throwing this Exception message, it is for some other reason.  In my case, Spark was crashing with this message right after this warning:

```
20/11/13 12:41:51 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 32320bc7-d7ba-49b4-8a56-1166a4f2d6db, runId = d7cc93c2-41ef-4765-aecd-9cd453c25905] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
```

This warning can be hidden by setting spark.executor.processTreeMetrics.enabled to false.  To quote Mr. Poon again, "it is a minor bug that you see this warning. But it can be safely ignored."

Answer (score 4):

Running on Windows, I received the same error. I resolved adding my python executable to my environment variables:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON = C:\wherever\python.exe
```

The three variables I needed to add are below. [image]

While this did not eliminate the warning message it allowed the program to run to completion without freezing or failing after the warninig.