# Getting error while setting pyspark environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>pyspark
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
20/05/18 10:55:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0-preview2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020 22:20:19)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> 20/05/18 10:55:56 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
```

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257377/encountering-warn-procfsmetricsgetter-exception-when-trying-to-compute-pagesi

Comment: I tried that too, I added my Spark/python path to the environment but still i face the same issue. "ProcessTree metrics is stopped"

Comment: Hmm... what do you get with echo %PYTHONPATH% ?  (hoping I'll see smth obvious)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encountering " WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize" error when running Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257377/encountering-warn-procfsmetricsgetter-exception-when-trying-to-compute-pagesi)

Answer (score 1):

Following up to my comment, I wanted to see the current *value* of your PYTHONPATH and PATH environment variables. Here's an example from my machine. Just post the text in red, in other words the entire output of the echo command:
[image]

edit: disclaimer - I haven't run spark at all, just interested in it and am sifting through the documentation because I plan to learn it at some point.

## PATH env-var

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
    C:\Program Files\jdk-14.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-14.0.1
    C:\Hadoop\bin
    C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
(i) C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src
    C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
    C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
    C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Ok, so unpacking your PATH env-var (above) we see you're using "spark-3.0.0-**preview2**" (i).  Hmm... from the [Spark download page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) (emphasis added): "Preview releases are ***not meant to be functional***, i.e. they can and highly likely will ***contain critical bugs or documentation errors***. The latest preview release is Spark 3.0.0-preview2, published on Dec 23, 2019."
(edit: fwiw, I think it is a bit unfair that the download-page's drop list *defaults* to a preview version so I can understand why you chose that)

Personally I would look at using a different version of Spark (by different I mean older and more stable).
Also, if you know linux *at all* I'd suggest doing this in a virtual machine. Maybe try this article on Medium: "[Practical Apache Spark in 10 minutes.](https://medium.com/data-science-school/practical-apache-spark-in-10-minutes-part-1-ubuntu-installation-f69bbb17ee9d)"

But if you *really* have to use Windows I'd look for an older (and more stable) version of Spark.

## Suggested PYTHONPATH

From that [**other issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257377/encountering-warn-procfsmetricsgetter-exception-when-trying-to-compute-pagesi) I mentioned, they talk about pointing your PYTHONPATH env-var to SPARK_HOME as follows:

```
Adding PYTHONPATH environment variable with value as:
(ii) set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip:%PYTHONPATH%
```

Let's split out those directories for PYTHONPATH from (ii) we get:

```
(iii) %SPARK_HOME%\python
 (iv) %SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-<version>-src.zip
  (v) %PYTHONPATH%
```

Since we're on Windows it looks like the ':%PYTHONPATH%' at the end of (ii) is a typo (see between (iii) and (iv) above). Colons on unix/linux, semicolons on windows.

Anyway, if I *had* to make this work I'd start by looking to see if the folders (iii) and (iv) actually exist. That means starting with the value of your SPARK_HOME env-var.

Note the  part of (iv), it won't literally be "". For example, if you do go ahead with the preview release that might be something like "3.0.0-preview2".
(fwiw, this is also why I was also asking for the value of your PYTHONPATH env-var).

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\jdk-14.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-14.0.1;C:\Hadoop\bin;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

Comment: Cool, also please post value of your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I think that `:` is just a typo and should be a `;` so that it just adds the two paths stated to the exising value of %PYTHONPATH%

Comment: I'm using the non-preview 3.0.0 and still getting the same error.