# WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm using Python 3.8 and when I try to run bin\pyspark under my SPARK_HOME directory , I'm getting the following error :

```
 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
```

I tried every possible solution on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work . I set my PYTHONPATH , Java Home etc.

Can someone please help me resolve this error ?

I'm using Spark 3.0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encountering " WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize" error when running Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257377/encountering-warn-procfsmetricsgetter-exception-when-trying-to-compute-pagesi)